# shared_ptr to vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have the following class

```
struct Images {
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<byte[]> > ptr_vector;
}
```

wouldn't putting `ptr_vector` in a `std::shared_ptr` be more efficient when copying `Images`?
namely doing    `Images A; Images B = A;`

```
struct Images {  
  std::shared_ptr< std::vector<std::shared_ptr<byte[]>> > vector_ptr;
}
```

instead of copying the vector and increment multiple shared_ptr reference count, only one is performed here.

is there any problem/limitation with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, copying is more efficient, if you must copy a pointer only.

The limitation is with any pointer, you share common data. When you modify one `struct Images` the other one is modified as well.

If you want to share data, you can also think about having `std::shared_ptr<Images>`

```
struct Images {
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<byte[]> > ptr_vector;
};

std::shared_ptr<Images> images1, images2;
```

This will avoid copying large data sets as well.

Comment: `ptr_vector` never get modified, guess I will go with wrapping it in a shared_ptr, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestions are:

1. Copy `ptr_vector`; you get a new vector that can be change independently of the original.
2. Wrap `ptr_vector` in another shared pointer and copy that; you get an alias to the original vector.

If your intent is to create an alias, then then go with option 2. If your intent is to create a copy go with option 1.

Figure out which of those is what you want and do that - doing the wrong thing very quickly isn't efficient.